# I cant get stories from Hacker News API

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { forkJoin, from, Observable } from 'rxjs';

const baseUrl = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/';
const topStoriesUrl = `${baseUrl}topstories.json`;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoriesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getItems(ids: number[]): Observable<any> {
    return from(ids).pipe(
      mergeMap(id => <Observable<any>> this.http.get(`${baseUrl}item/${id}`))
   );
  }
  getTopIds(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(topStoriesUrl);
  }
}
```

TS file:

```
  constructor(private service: StoriesService) { }
  topIds: number[] = [];
  topNews: Array<Object> = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTopIds();
    this.getTopNews();
    console.log(this.topNews);
    
  }

  getTopIds() {
    this.service.getTopIds().subscribe((data) => this.topIds = data);
  }
  getTopNews() {
    this.service.getItems(this.topIds).subscribe(data => this.topNews = data);
  }
```

topIds works perfectly but for some reason topNews returns empty array, not sure how to get this to work. Im stuck on this for a while. Also tried to do services with forkJoin but always failed to. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> topIds works perfectly but for some reason topNews returns empty array, not sure how to get this to work. Im stuck on this for a while. Also tried to do services with forkJoin but always failed to.

You are calling `this.service.getItems(this.topIds)` even before `this.topIds = data` gets executed within the subscribe method.

HTTP calls are asynchronous, and hence the call to get the items should happen only once you have ids available i.e once the `getTopIds()` is completed.

You can try something as below:

```ts
this.myService.getTopIds().pipe(
  tap(ids => { this.topIds = ids }),  // required only if you need to store ids
  switchMap(ids => this.myService.getItems(ids))
).subscribe(data => {
  this.topNews = data;
  console.log(this.topNews);
});
```

The above code will get the ids, and store it in `this.topIds`, and then make a call to get the items.

The `getItems()` logic should be as mentioned in one of the other answers:

```ts
getItems(ids: number[]): Observable<any> {
    const observables = ids.map((id) => this.http.get(`${baseUrl}item/${id}`));
    return forkJoin(observables);
}
```

Comment: Wow ty so much so far its working

Answer (score 0):

Change getItems to :-

```
getItems(ids: number[]): Observable<any> {
    const observables = ids.map((id) => this.http.get(`${baseUrl}item/${id}`);
    return forkJoin(observables);
}
```

forkjoin basically will call all apis parallely and will return the response when all api completes in a array in same sequence the ids array converted into observables array.

Comment: thanks I changed it, but it still returns empty array

Comment: you checked network tab that your api is returning any data?

Comment: and did you try to print the response in your subsribe block?

Comment: it doesnt return any data in network only from getTopIds();

Comment: that depends on api. did you check api response?